# Git: Undo a pushed commit in which a new user accidentally deleted all files

Tags: git

We added a new user, who did a put pull and wrongly thought it was successful.

They then did a git push, but since they had no files, they deleted all the files in the entire project.

Right now, we need to undo what happened and roll the project back to the commit before everything was deleted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Pull the latest version into your local repository
- Do a `git revert HEAD`
- Push the new commit

`git revert` creates a new commit that reverts all changes introduced by the specified commit.

For a bit more info and background, see [this blog post](http://christoph.ruegg.name/blog/2010/5/5/git-howto-revert-a-commit-already-pushed-to-a-remote-reposit.html).

Answer (score 1):

You should first check what happened to your main repository. Was the whole branch deleted (requires forced push) or did the new user just introduce a new commit erasing all files.

If the branch was deleted, push it back from another developers repository.

If the new user just deleted everything with one commit, go to the main repository and do a

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

to get rid of the offending commit. I would advice against `git revert` unless many people have already pulled the mistake into their repositories. If you revert, you will have a record of this mistake in your history. If you reset, there is no sign of this ever happening. But reset only if the mistaken commit hasn't spread out yet!

Comment: the risk of messing stuff up for other people when force-pushing (rewriting published history) should not be underestimated

Comment: True, this depends on the team size. If it's a team of e.g five people working in the same floor, it's easy to check if anyone has pulled from the repository yet. But if it's a public project, one should never even think about rewriting history.